# App crashes when using setErrorEnabled with floating editText

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

Please,I need some help,my app is crashing when I open activity in which i have declared app:errorEnabled=true in xml file for TextInputLayout i use more than tutorial but nothing work like[User input errors](http://www.materialdoc.com/user-input-errors/)

xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyErrorText"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.TextInputLayout.Red">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

style:

```
 <style name="MyErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
</style>
```

Activity:

```
 tilEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.tilEmail);
    tilEmail.setError(null);


 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        tilEmail.setError("Email name is required"); // show error
```

}

Error Stack:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.newsolution.jiibli, PID: 14042
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newsolution.jiibli/com.newsolution.jiibli.Activity.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245)
at com.newsolution.jiibli.Activity.Login.onCreate(Login.java:65)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245) 
at com.newsolution.jiibli.Activity.Login.onCreate(Login.java:65) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:402)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:763)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:685)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:681)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:677)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:297)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:119)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:82)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2245) 
at com.newsolution.jiibli.Activity.Login.onCreate(Login.java:65) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
```

gradle:

```
   compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
repositories {
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile(name: 'osmbonuspack_v5.3', ext: 'aar')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:2.3.6'
compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
```

}

Comment: Can you add your gradle files please.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: which is the exact line [code wise] that is throwing this, as I see blogs have different ways to approach this.

Comment: @AmalKronz the link you have provided  says there is issue with TextInput Layout if you are using this with  sdkversion 23?

Comment: i change the compile and build sdk to 21 but another error appear(Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. in value_23v)

Comment: @AmalKronz : Not sure if you found the issue and solved it?

Comment: I am not, and another problem appear the red line that appear when wrong spelling when i press the EditText to change text the pp crash with IOException null inputStream :(

Answer (score 2):

As showing in your code you are using some custom theme for TextInputLayout i.e @style/TextLabel. Just make sure parent of TextLabel theme is **Theme.Design** or something like Theme.Design.Light

Comment: ya the problem because of that style but Theme.Design  not define

Comment: That's what i am trying to say defined something Theme.Design.Light in your custom style TextLabel if you want your custom theme for textInputLayout see  <style name="TextLabel" parent="Theme.Design.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_txt</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="textColorError">@color/design_textinput_error_color_light</item>

    </style>

Comment: Theme.Design.Light not define in my app

Answer (score 1):

the problem occurs because of `android:theme="@style/TextLabel"`
just remove it from code and it's solved
thanks to all

Comment: Perfect Answer, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2019, Google wants you to use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and if you want to set your own theme to a TextInputLayout, make sure you set your custom style as follows:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="...">...</item>
</style>
```

Note that FilledBox is the default theme of TextInputLayout. There are multiple themes possible to choose from depending on your needs, the differences are documented here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

---

If you are still using `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`, this should hopefully work:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="...">...</item>
</style>
```